# angular drop down selected ng-model not binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently having a problem with selecting drop downs which are not working correctly with `angularjs`. Couldn't find anything that relates to my problem. It seems odd.

I am a newbie to `angularjs` so please forgive my ignorance

I am currently trying to retrofit `angularjs` onto my `MVC5` application.

Here are the issues;

1. When `$scope.selected = $scope.options[0]` is declared it is assigned, but as if the select list does not recognize the model's object and creates a new option
2. Once you change the selected option on the drop-down, selected the object in scope is now empty?

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ynJ8cwobN8bNjo0oTN0Z?p=preview) is the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comprehension expression is incorrect. It looks like you want the whole option as the selected value so use this:

```
ng-options="o.text for o in options"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="o.code as o.text for o in options"></select>
```

to

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="o as o.text for o in options"></select>
```

to make it work as you expected.

because the documentation says `select as label for (key , value) in object` but in your case select is equal to code property of the object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="o.code as o.text for o in options"></select>
  <br />Code: {{ selected.code }}
  <br />Text: {{ selected.text }}
</div>
```

Your ng-model will contain the value of the select (in this case the index [0,1,2,etc]). So you are attempting something like this "1.code" or "2.text".